# Selecting 1 record based on last unique value that is on another column

Tags: sql

I need help with the example below, this example is the result of joining 4 tables with a left outer join because I need to check that all column even knowing that could get null values, but what I really want is to get 1 record for each C6 based on the last o higher value on c6.

```
C1  C2  C3  C4  C5  C6
4   A   MM  90  GT  798
4   A   MM  90  GT  625
4   A   MM  90  GT  354
4   A   MM  90  GT  547
5   K   EE  60  SV  213
5   K   EE  60  SV  235
5   K   EE  60  SV  236
9   O   WW  40  PE  456
9   O   WW  40  PE  487
9   O   WW  40  PE  982
```

The query that I am using is like this:

```html
SELECT distinct   C1, C2, C3, C4,C5,C6
   --,row_number() OVER(partition by c6 ORDER BY c1 asc)       
  FROM table1 n
  left outer join  table 2 j on j.cad = n.Cad and j.P = n.P and j.H = 'Name'
  left outer join  table 3 k on k.id = n.id
  left outer join  table 4 m on m.u = n.u and m.s = n.s and m.Cad = n.Cad  and n.P = m.P
where NOT EXISTS   (SELECT 1 from table 5 v WHERE N.U=v.U and N.S=v.S 
                       and N.Cad=v.Cad and N.P=v.P) and n.Cad is not null
        and C6 is not null
```

Comment: What are your expected results?  Not completely understanding your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the below query.

```
   With cte_1
     As(   SELECT C1, C2, C3, C4,C5,C6
      ,row_number() OVER(partition by c1,c2,c3,c4,c5    ORDER BY c6 desc)   RNO  
      FROM table1 n
         left outer join  table 2 j on j.cad = n.Cad and j.P = n.P and j.H = 'Name'
         left outer join  table 3 k on k.id = n.id
         left outer join  table 4 m on m.u = n.u and m.s = n.s and m.Cad = n.Cad  and n.P = m.P
        where NOT EXISTS   (SELECT 1 from table 5 v      WHERE N.U=v.U and N.S=v.S 
                       and N.Cad=v.Cad and N.P=v.P) and n.Cad is not null
                       and C6 is not null)

       SELECT C1, C2, C3, C4,C5,C6 FROM cte_1
      WHERE RNO=1
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I tested the query suggested and noticed some scenarios that I want to share with you the original query, the one using distinct , not joining the table 4 and comment the row_number, the query brought 3621 records, if I add the join of table 4 and/or the row_number then it bring me 3418 or if I use your query it bring the same amount but why could be it happened

Comment: I think when you are partition the data with C1, C2, C3, C4,C5,C6 there maybe duplicates in your tables. And that got eliminated when you are applying the filter condition RNO =1

Comment: Just comment the RNO=1, you can see the full records from your table which satisfies the join condition..